# problem in Parsing json in SWIFT for iOS developing

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone, xcode

I have an Error in parsing JSON Format form an ASMX Web service, 
My Code is

```
func getData() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.11.188/getItems.asmx/theItems")
    let theCategory = "ALL"
    let theSubCategory = "ALL"
    let postString = "theCategory=\(theCategory)&theSubCategory=\(theSubCategory)"
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, respons, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error conning to server \(error)")
        } else {
            if let respons = respons as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if respons.statusCode == 200 {
                    print(data!)
                    if let data = data {
                        do {
                            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([ITEMS].self, from: data)
                            print(json)
                        } catch let parsingError {
                            print("Error parsing json \(parsingError)")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error in responce code.... \(respons.statusCode)")
                }
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I am using the decoder struct in this code:

```
struct ITEMS: Codable {
    let CODE:String
    let CAT_ID:String
    let SUB_ID:String
    let PRODUCT_AR:String
    let PRODUCT_EN:String
    let OLD_PRICE:String
    let NEW_PRICE:String
    let UNIT:String
    let BARCODE:String
    let THE_DATE:String
    let TIME:String
}
```

The JSON value is

```
{ ITEMS : [{"CODE":111,"CAT_ID":203,"SUB_ID":null,"PRODUCT_AR":"ITEM 1","PRODUCT_EN":"ITEM 1","OLD_PRICE":133.0035,"NEW_PRICE":109,"UNIT":null,"BARCODE":"328031002009","THE_DATE":"\/Date(1553673958397)\/","TIME":"11:05 AM"},
           {"CODE":222,"CAT_ID":201,"SUB_ID":null,"PRODUCT_AR":"ITEM 2","PRODUCT_EN":"ITEM 2","OLD_PRICE":18.95,"NEW_PRICE":9.95,"UNIT":null,"BARCODE":"628103400012","THE_DATE":"\/Date(1553673958260)\/","TIME":"11:05 AM"}]}
```

but this code returns an Error

> Error parsing JSON Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you print exactly? Could you print `let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`?

Comment: Unrelated but everything *SNAKE_CASE_CAPITALIZED* is horrible. Please conform to the Swift [naming convention](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

Comment: The issue looks like the JSON. 

`ITEMS` is not valid JSON. It should be `"ITEMS"` if you want to use that key.

also if `"SUB_ID"` can be `null` you will need to make `SUB_ID` an optional

Comment: Dear MR.Larme I already use your method String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) but I found the JSON Result came with <?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?> <string xmlns=".......................... I think that is the probem did you know how to remove the XML tags ??

Comment: So your API returns XML? Can it return JSON? Maybe with a HTTP header (Content-type application/json)? And we don't know that even by removing the XML it's valid JSON inside it. And clearly, embedding JSON inside XML is overkilled, so your objects might be in XML and not in JSON at all.

Answer (score 0):

as you are writing this,

`let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([ITEMS].self, from: data)`

it must ask for array of `ITEMS` to be parsed, but your JSON is just an object not an array (It starts with `{ITEMS: [array_here]}`).

For solving this issue, you need to make your struct like below and parse data into that object.

```
struct ITEMS: Codable {
    let CODE:String
    let CAT_ID:String
    let SUB_ID:String
    let PRODUCT_AR:String
    let PRODUCT_EN:String
    let OLD_PRICE:String
    let NEW_PRICE:String
    let UNIT:String
    let BARCODE:String
    let THE_DATE:String
    let TIME:String
}

struct MyAPIData: Codable {
    let ITEMS: [ITEMS]
}
```

Now parse data using below line of code,

`let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyAPIData.self, from: data)`

Answer (score 0):

There were wrong types used in your struct, here is the fixed struct

```
struct ITEM: Codable {
    let CODE:Int           // not String
    let CAT_ID:Int         // not String
    let SUB_ID:Int?        // its null in JSON, use either Int? or String?
    let PRODUCT_AR: String
    let PRODUCT_EN: String
    let OLD_PRICE:Double   // not String
    let NEW_PRICE:Double   // not String
    let UNIT:String?
    let BARCODE:String
    let THE_DATE:String
    let TIME:String
}
```

Since you JSON has a root element `ITEMS`, you need to decode using this struct

```
struct BaseItems: Codable {
    let ITEMS: [ITEM] // Actual array of items are within this JSON element
}
```

**Usage:**

```
do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseItems.self, from: data)
    print(decoded.ITEMS)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```